# How to remove element's space occupied when use position:sticky?

Tags: html, css

The html struct

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="sticky">
    sticky menu
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    other body
  </div>
</div>
```

The css style

```
<style>
 html body {
     margin: 0;
     padding:0 ;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .main {
     width:100%;
     max-width: 300px;
     height: 480px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: yellow;
     position: relative;
     margin-top: 50px;
 }
 .body {
     height: 720px;
 }
 .sticky {
     position: sticky;
     z-index:10;
     top: 0;
     background-color: blue;
     display: inline-block;
     transform: translate(-100%,0);
 }
</style>
```

[image: sticky]

I want to remove the space occupied by the red box, One of the solutions is make `.sticky` inside `position: absolute`, but I can't change html struct, any solution to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use float and then use shape-outside to make the element takes 0 space.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.body {
  height: 720px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left; /* here */
  shape-outside: inset(50%); /* and here */
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sticky">
    sticky menu
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    other body
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of position sticky, use position fixed and add padding to the body container

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).